# Inserting space in HTML Text

Tags: html, padding, spacing

I have written an HTML code for an email, however I want a little space/padding on top of the first Welcome and the bottom of the Welcome in footer. I don't want to add a  tag as that gives more space than required. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

The code is as follows:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container" style="background-color:#00843d; width= '60px'; ">
    <p align="left"><b> <font face="Franklin Gothic Book" size="6" color="white" style="margin-left: 30px">Welcome</font> </b> </p>
    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f4f4f4;">
      <p align="justify" style="margin-left: 30px; margin-right: 30px;">
        <br> Lorem ipsum,
        <br>
        <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu malis verterem scribentur usu. Falli error harum vim id, his eu paulo labore. Has tibique facilisis ei, per duis delenit laboramus in, utroque tractatos duo in. Suas fuisset ei per. Eos at dolor vivendum oportere.
        Ne partiendo constituto voluptatibus
        <br>
        <br>
        <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu malis verterem scribentur usu. Falli error harum vim id, his eu paulo labore. Has tibique facilisis ei, per duis delenit laboramus in, utroque tractatos duo in. Suas fuisset ei per. Eos at dolor vivendum oportere.
        Ne partiendo constituto voluptatibus
        <br>
        <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu malis verterem scribentur usu. Falli error harum vim id, his eu paulo labore. Has tibique facilisis ei, per duis delenit laboramus in, utroque tractatos duo in. Suas fuisset ei per. Eos at dolor vivendum oportere.
        Ne partiendo constituto voluptatibus
        <br>
        <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu malis verterem scribentur usu. Falli error harum vim id, his eu paulo labore. Has tibique facilisis ei, per duis delenit laboramus in, utroque tractatos duo in. Suas fuisset ei per. Eos at dolor vivendum oportere.
        Ne partiendo constituto voluptatibus
        <br>
        <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu malis verterem scribentur usu. Falli error harum vim id, his eu paulo labore. Has tibique facilisis ei, per duis delenit laboramus in, utroque tractatos duo in. Suas fuisset ei per. Eos at dolor vivendum oportere.
        Ne partiendo constituto voluptatibus

      </p>
      <div class="container" style="background-color:#005a29;">
        <center>
          <footer>
            <p>
              <font face="Franklin Gothic Book" color="white">
                <br> Welcome
              </font>
            </p>
            <font face="Franklin Gothic Book" color="white">
            </font>
            <p></p>
          </footer>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just use `margin-top` or `padding-top`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just a `padding` like normally do to add spaces?

Just add `padding-top` to the container of the top Welcome message and `padding-bottom` to the bottom welcome message.

```html
<html>
<div class="container">
  <div class="container" style="background-color:#00843d; width= '60px'; padding-top:10px;">
    <p align="left"><b> <font face = "Franklin Gothic Book" size = "6" color = "white" style = "margin-left: 30px">Welcome</font> </b> </p>
    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f4f4f4;">
      <p align="justify" style="margin-left: 30px; margin-right: 30px;">
        </br>
        Lorem ipsum,
        </br>
        </br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu malis verterem scribentur usu. Falli error harum vim id, his eu paulo labore. Has tibique facilisis ei, per duis delenit laboramus in, utroque tractatos duo in. Suas fuisset ei per. Eos at dolor vivendum oportere. Ne partiendo
        constituto voluptatibus
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu malis verterem scribentur usu. Falli error harum vim id, his eu paulo labore. Has tibique facilisis ei, per duis delenit laboramus in, utroque tractatos duo in. Suas fuisset ei per. Eos at dolor vivendum oportere. Ne partiendo
        constituto voluptatibus
        </br>
        </br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu malis verterem scribentur usu. Falli error harum vim id, his eu paulo labore. Has tibique facilisis ei, per duis delenit laboramus in, utroque tractatos duo in. Suas fuisset ei per. Eos at dolor vivendum oportere. Ne partiendo
        constituto voluptatibus
        </br>
        </br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu malis verterem scribentur usu. Falli error harum vim id, his eu paulo labore. Has tibique facilisis ei, per duis delenit laboramus in, utroque tractatos duo in. Suas fuisset ei per. Eos at dolor vivendum oportere. Ne partiendo
        constituto voluptatibus
        </br>
        </br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu malis verterem scribentur usu. Falli error harum vim id, his eu paulo labore. Has tibique facilisis ei, per duis delenit laboramus in, utroque tractatos duo in. Suas fuisset ei per. Eos at dolor vivendum oportere. Ne partiendo
        constituto voluptatibus

      </p>
      <div class="container" style="background-color:#005a29; padding-bottom:10px;">
        <center>
          <footer>
            <p>
              <font face="Franklin Gothic Book" color="white">
                </br>
                Welcome</a>
            </p>
            </font>
            </p>
          </footer>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try adding something like this to the top

element

```
<p align = "left" style="padding:10px 0;">
```

or

```
<p align = "left" style="padding-top:10px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
p.header {
    padding-top: 15px;
}
footer.footer {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="container" style="background-color:#00843d; width= '60px'; ">
        <p align="left" class="header"><b>
                <font face="Franklin Gothic Book" size="6" color="white" style="margin-left: 30px">Welcome</font>
            </b> </p>
        <div class="container" style="background-color:#f4f4f4;">
            <p align="justify" style="margin-left: 30px; margin-right: 30px;">
                </br>
                Lorem ipsum,
                </br>
                </br>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu malis verterem scribentur usu. Falli error harum vim id, his eu paulo labore. Has tibique facilisis ei, per duis delenit laboramus in, utroque tractatos duo in. Suas fuisset ei per. Eos at dolor vivendum oportere. Ne partiendo constituto voluptatibus
                </br>
                </br>
                </br>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu malis verterem scribentur usu. Falli error harum vim id, his eu paulo labore. Has tibique facilisis ei, per duis delenit laboramus in, utroque tractatos duo in. Suas fuisset ei per. Eos at dolor vivendum oportere. Ne partiendo constituto voluptatibus
                </br>
                </br>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu malis verterem scribentur usu. Falli error harum vim id, his eu paulo labore. Has tibique facilisis ei, per duis delenit laboramus in, utroque tractatos duo in. Suas fuisset ei per. Eos at dolor vivendum oportere. Ne partiendo constituto voluptatibus
                </br>
                </br>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu malis verterem scribentur usu. Falli error harum vim id, his eu paulo labore. Has tibique facilisis ei, per duis delenit laboramus in, utroque tractatos duo in. Suas fuisset ei per. Eos at dolor vivendum oportere. Ne partiendo constituto voluptatibus
                </br>
                </br>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu malis verterem scribentur usu. Falli error harum vim id, his eu paulo labore. Has tibique facilisis ei, per duis delenit laboramus in, utroque tractatos duo in. Suas fuisset ei per. Eos at dolor vivendum oportere. Ne partiendo constituto voluptatibus

            </p>
            <div class="container" style="background-color:#005a29;">
                <center>
                    <footer class="footer">
                        <p>
                            <font face="Franklin Gothic Book" color="white"></br>
                                Welcome</a>
                        </p>
                        </font>
                        </p>
                    </footer>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help